# Ultimate Member directory - How to display members in 4 columns instead of 3?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, grid

**///Ultimate Member is a wordpress plugin///**

I am trying to make the Ultimate Member directory to display members in 4 columns instead of 3 (3 columns is set by default). I tried to edit the "members-grid.php" file but not sure what exactly to change (I am new in php). 
I will paste the code here and if someone wants to help me I will be very thankful!

```
<div class="um-members">

<div class="um-gutter-sizer"></div>

<?php $i = 0; foreach( um_members('users_per_page') as $member) { $i++; um_fetch_user( $member ); ?>

<div class="um-member um-role-<?php echo um_user('role'); ?> <?php echo um_user('account_status'); ?> <?php if ($cover_photos) { echo 'with-cover'; } ?>">

    <span class="um-member-status <?php echo um_user('account_status'); ?>"><?php echo um_user('account_status_name'); ?></span>

    <?php
    if ($cover_photos) {
        $sizes = um_get_option('cover_thumb_sizes');
        if ( $ultimatemember->mobile->isTablet() ) {
            $cover_size = $sizes[1];
        } else {
            $cover_size = $sizes[0];
        }
    ?>

    <div class="um-member-cover" data-ratio="<?php echo um_get_option('profile_cover_ratio'); ?>">
        <div class="um-member-cover-e"><a href="<?php echo um_user_profile_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(um_user('display_name')); ?>"><?php echo um_user('cover_photo', $cover_size); ?></a></div>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php if ($profile_photo) {
        $default_size = str_replace( 'px', '', um_get_option('profile_photosize') );
        $corner = um_get_option('profile_photocorner');
    ?>
    <div class="um-member-photo radius-<?php echo $corner; ?>"><a href="<?php echo um_user_profile_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(um_user('display_name')); ?>"><?php echo get_avatar( um_user('ID'), $default_size ); ?></a></div>
    <?php } ?>

                <div class="um-member-card <?php if (!$profile_photo) { echo 'no-photo'; } ?>">

                    <?php if ( $show_name ) { ?>
                    <div class="um-member-name"><a href="<?php echo um_user_profile_url(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr(um_user('display_name')); ?>"><?php echo um_user('display_name', 'html'); ?></a></div>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php do_action('um_members_just_after_name', um_user('ID'), $args); ?>

                    <?php do_action('um_members_after_user_name', um_user('ID'), $args); ?>

                    <?php
                    if ( $show_tagline && is_array( $tagline_fields ) ) {

                        um_fetch_user( $member );

                        foreach( $tagline_fields as $key ) {
                            if ( $key && um_filtered_value( $key ) ) {
                                $value = um_filtered_value( $key );


                    ?>

                    <div class="um-member-tagline um-member-tagline-<?php echo $key;?>"><?php echo $value; ?></div>

                    <?php
                            } // end if
                        } // end foreach
                    } // end if $show_tagline
                    ?>

                    <?php if ( $show_userinfo ) { ?>

                    <div class="um-member-meta-main">

                        <?php if ( $userinfo_animate ) { ?>
                        <div class="um-member-more"><a href="#"><i class="um-faicon-angle-down"></i></a></div>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <div class="um-member-meta <?php if ( !$userinfo_animate ) { echo 'no-animate'; } ?>">

                            <?php foreach( $reveal_fields as $key ) {
                                    if ( $key && um_filtered_value( $key ) ) {
                                        $value = um_filtered_value( $key );

                            ?>

                            <div class="um-member-metaline um-member-metaline-<?php echo $key; ?>"><span><strong><?php echo $ultimatemember->fields->get_label( $key ); ?>:</strong> <?php echo $value; ?></span></div>

                            <?php 
                                }
                            } 
                            ?>

                            <?php if ( $show_social ) { ?>
                            <div class="um-member-connect">

                                <?php $ultimatemember->fields->show_social_urls(); ?>

                            </div>
                            <?php } ?>

                        </div>

                        <div class="um-member-less"><a href="#"><i class="um-faicon-angle-up"></i></a></div>

                    </div>

                    <?php } ?>

                </div>

</div>

<?php 
um_reset_user_clean();
} // end foreach

um_reset_user();
?>

<div class="um-clear"></div>
```

Comment: I can't see there anything what could split your items to 3 columns, so I think that must be done in css.

Comment: @Joint Can you find it in css: [link](https://royalcastagency.com/find-talent/)[link] , because I cant :D

Comment: ok, I see what is going on, you have masonry on your website, which in default set layout to 3 columns and additionaly your css sets width for `.um-member` to 29.6%. Please check if your theme has some settings in wordpress panel to change it, because if you don't know well javascript then it will be hard to change that in code.

Answer (score 2):

Insert this css in Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS and then hard refesh the page:

```
.um-directory .um-members-wrapper .um-members.um-members-grid .um-member{
    width:23% !important;
    margin-left:1% !important;
    margin-right:1% !important;
}

.um-directory .um-members-wrapper .um-members.um-members-grid .um-gutter-sizer{
    width:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: This is also a good thread to check out - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/more-then-3-members-per-row-in-grid-view/